# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Then

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Suppose that $T \in \mathbb{L}(V)$ has $dimV$ distinct eigen value and that $S \in \mathbb{L}(V)$ has the same eigen vectors as T (not necessarily the same eigen values). Prove that $ST=TS$

This is an exercise in my book but I couldnt solve it. Please guide me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- For any eigenvector $v$ of $S$, show that $STv = TSv$
- Use the fact that there exists a basis of $V$ whose elements are eigenvectors of $S$

Comment: I know this. This hint is given by my teacher but I couldnt do this

Comment: @JalilAhmad If you had a hint for the problem, then that is [context for the question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) that you should have included in your post. In any case, what do you mean by "I couldn't do this"? Were you able to do the first step of showing that $STv = TSv$ when $v$ is an eigenvector of $S$?